# extract specific folder in shell command using unzip

Tags: shell, zip, extract

My backup.zip has the following structure.

OverallFolder

> lots of files and subfolders inside

i used this unzip backup.zip -d ~/public_html/demo

so i end up with ~/public_html/demo/OverallFolder/my other files.

How do i extract so that i end up with all my files INSIDE OverallFolder GOING DIRECTLY into ~public_html/demo?

~/public_html/demo/my other files 
like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can't find any options to do that, this is the last resort

`mv ~/public_html/demo/OverallFolder/* ~/public_html/demo/`

Answer (score 0):

```
(cd ~public_html/demo; unzip $OLDPWD/backup.zip)
```

This, in a subshell, changes to your destination directory, unzips the file from your source directory, and when the subshell exits, leaves you back in your source directory.

That, or something similar, should work in most shells.